# Can groups be expanded when querying which students are associated with a class notebook?

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

We currently query for the list of students associated with a class notebook via:

```
/api/v1.0/me/notes/classnotebooks/{id}/students
```

Should a group be associated with the class notebook then we get principalType=Group and an id in the form:

```
c:0o.c|federateddirectoryclaimprovider|{id}
```

So is it possible to expand the members of the associated group(s) within this call? If not, what is the format of this id? To use it via the graph api requires an id so is it safe to assume that the id will always be the 3rd piped element?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this for my application as well. After conferring with the onenote team a few months ago it came down to that you cannot expand these groups inside the onenote api. You must authenticate to the graph api and use the groups functions there. The downside of this is that the graph api permissions to expand a group require an administrator to grant them. So in the end all I could do was recommend the users create class notebooks using the student email list rather than an azure group. (on your final point the format should remain consistent the third piped element is the group id you can pass the graph api)

specifically the below endpoint to get a groups members

```
'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/myorganization/groups/' . $group_id . '/members'
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming, much appreciated